# ui-grid export all filtered data to csv

Tags: angularjs, csv, angular-ui-grid

I have some fairly large data (~100k rows) with filtering on every column and paging enabled. It's all displayed and manipulated client side.

I'd like to be able to export all the filtered results, not just what's displayed in the first page.

The workaround would be to change the pagination size to something larger than the resulting filtered result, but that just seems cumbersome. Is there a better way to do this?

Someone had asked this question in https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3954 but never got an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to do it.  Export visible exports the currently visible rows.  Pagination works by changing which rows are visible - so the visible rows are those on the current page.  Export all data works by exporting all the data whether it's visible or not, so it exports rows that have been filtered out.

In theory this could be implemented, we'd need to reinstitute the "invisibleReason" flag which I think is still mostly implemented but not used in the code, and then set the visibleReason to "pagination" on those rows that the pagination feature makes invisible.  We could then have exporter manually process the rows and include those for which the only invisibleReason was pagination.

It's quite a lot of fiddling around, but it's plausible someone could submit a PR with that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {

            gridApi.core.on.rowsVisibleChanged($scope, function () {
                // match export enabled per row to visible property. This is in order to force export only of filtered data.
                gridApi.grid.rows.forEach(function (row) {
                    row.exporterEnableExporting = row.visible;
                });
            });
        }
```